# Free Monads in Julia Programming

Tags: functional-programming, julia, monads, free-monad

I'm learning about Free Monads and I was wondering how one could implement it in the Julia programming language. I've seen the implementation in Haskell, but I'm having a hard time porting it to Julia.

Here is the idea. A free monoid is a list. It's definition in Haskell is:

```hs
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

We can code this in Julia using the following:

```
struct Nil end
struct Cons{T}
  val::T
  next::Union{Cons{T},Nil} # n.b. abstract type!
end
List{T} = Union{Cons{T}, Nil}
```

Another variation of this in Julia would be:

```
abstract type List{T} end
struct Nil{T} <: List{T} end
struct Cons{T} <: List{T}
  val::T
  next::List{T} # n.b. abstract type!
end
```

Now, a Free monad is similar to a list, but it instead defines a "list" in the functor category. Here is the Haskell definition:

```hs
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))
```

I'm having trouble with such recursive definition. In Julia we cannot simply define such thing.

Comment: Ain't gonna work. You need higher kinded types for that, and Julia's type system doesn't do that.

Comment: Wouldn't be able to do it with macros? I'm thinking of something similar to MLStyle.jl